# Will CTE's and traditional subqueries generally create comparable query plans

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

Take the following queries.

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT
        *,
        RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Field1, Field2 ORDER BY Field3 DESC)
    FROM Table)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
WHERE RowNumber  <= 3
ORDER BY Field1,RowNumber DESC
```

And

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        *,
        RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Field1, Field2 ORDER BY Field3 DESC)
    FROM Table
)AS X
WHERE 
    X.RowNumber <= 3
ORDER BY 
    Field1,
    RowNumber DESC
```

I know some of the advantages of cte's including compacting code, readability of elaborate sub queries and techniques to work with recursion etc. etc.

That being said, in regards to compilation/optimization are these two queries identical?

Comment: These 2 certainly produced identical execution plans when I ran them.

Comment: Compilation/Optimization should NOT be your concern in a SQL query (assuming you use parameterized query). For the same reason you don't run benchmarks against how long it takes to compile your application. SQL Server should and does only compile the query once, and will cache the query plan against the query. So long as you use parameterized queries, the SQL Server will dig up the old query plan rather than compile the query.

Comment: Both queries are identical. But I prefer using `CTE` for clarity.

Comment: @Aron I have not done much benchmarking with cte and their non-cte equivalent as in my case it would be a waste of time. I apologize if my question was not clear. In regards to the query plan chosen, the two queries seem to be similar. I wonder if there are cases where identical queries with slightly different sql would produced vastly different query plans. Maybe someone reading this has done this. I have updated the question title

Comment: @Irb No there really shouldn't be any case where CTEs are different. Since SQL Server would have to substitute the CTE into the query as a subquery anyway. The one case where I can see a difference is recursive SQL, which is not possible without a CTE.

Comment: Dear @lrb your question is specific and you are comparing both query . both will be identical in  compilation/optimization.